# Get the redirected url when using angular $http

Tags: angularjs

The following url returns a random image based on a search term. To do this it redirects us to the url of the image it wants to show us.

https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water

Given that we call this url with angulars $http service, and want to save the specific image url, not the random search url, is there a way to find this url?

I've got this code in a service so far. I'm getting the image itself returned here, and had the same result in postman without any obvious place to get the url out:

```
 this.getImageUrl = function (query) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http
            .get('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?' + query)
            .then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e);
            });
        return deferred.
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you found solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry Artem.